# How To Upgrade Solr From 3.1 to 3.2 Without Reconfigure or Data Lost

Tags: java, solr

Only replace the start.jar or any other means?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start.jar is only a small wrapper to start up Jetty. It's not related to Solr. When upgrading, always see the release notes first ([here are the release notes for 3.2](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_2/solr/CHANGES.txt), there are no breaking changes), make the changes indicated there, then replace your solr.war and other apache-solr*.jar with the ones in the `dist` directory in the 3.2 distro.